# Change alpha in already existing ggplot with geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't create an reproducible script, so I am trying my best to provide enough information.

I want to take an existing ggplot2 plot:

```
recallPlot <- plot(marginal_effects(combinedData_model, spaghetti = TRUE, nsamples = 100), 
                   points = TRUE, 
                   point_args = c(alpha =0.5),
                   jitter_width = 0)
recallPlot <- recallPlot$objLocTargetRating 
recallPlot$layers[[1]]$position <- position_jitter(height = 0.01)
```

The result:
[image]

where I want to change the lines to black and set their alpha value to 0.01, but that's where I am stuck. Accessing the layers, `recallPlot$layers` gives me:

```
[[1]]
mapping: x = ~effect1__, y = ~resp__ 
geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_jitter 

[[2]]
mapping: group = ~sample__, colour = NULL 
geom_smooth: na.rm = FALSE, se = TRUE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity 

[[3]]
mapping: group = NULL 
geom_smooth: na.rm = FALSE, se = TRUE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity
```

Now, when I try to change the aes params

```
recallPlot$layers[[2]]$aes_params$colour <- 'black'
recallPlot$layers[[2]]$aes_params$alpha <- 0.1
```

the colour is changed but the alpha isn't:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to create a colour with an alpha value using `rgb()`:

```
recallPlot$layers[[2]]$aes_params$colour <- rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.01)
```